# Registry entry exists but sometimes I cannot read it

Tags: c#, registry

I read this registry setting many times, but sometimes not. This is very rarely, but was an accident in my client.

Is normal that sometimes ever entry exists in Windows registry i become default value instead really existed entry?

The same user reads the register 100 times and gets the default value a bit later.

```
public int GetDrukujSaldoOdbiorcy(int DefaultValue)
        {
            int result = DefaultValue;
            try
            {
                RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\BRMLM\MERA\USER_PARAM\Drukowanie");
                if (regKey != null)
                {
                    result = (int)regKey.GetValue("DrukujSaldoOdbiorcy", DefaultValue);
                    regKey.Close();
                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you don't have the permission to read from registry. You will have to understand your application permissions on the client machine.
In your code you should check first if you can read it like this:

```
public static bool CanReadKey(this RegistryPermission reg, string key)
{
    try
    {
        RegistryPermission r = new RegistryPermission(RegistryPermissionAccess.Read, key);
        r.Demand();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your case it is always default value when the key can't be read because the `try` will catch the exception and the `result` value remains with the default initialization that you have it ahead of the `try`.